# Issue in displaying array of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am having a dictionary declared like so `var arrayOfDictionary = [[:]]`. Now I have some data in my tableviewcell like `rate`, `id` etc. I'm storing these values in dictionary like so in `cellForRowAt`...

```
    var dictionary = ["id": "", "quantity": "","sellingPrice":""] as [String : Any]
    dictionary["id"] = product?.id
    dictionary["quantity"] = product?.quantity
    dictionary["sellingPrice"] = product?.theRate
    arrayOfDictionary.append(dictionary)
```

Now, when I print `arrayOfDictionary`, I get something like this...

```
[[:], [AnyHashable("id"): "5", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "499", AnyHashable("quantity"): "-1"], [AnyHashable("id"): "8", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "500", AnyHashable("quantity"): "79"], [AnyHashable("id"): "8", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "500", AnyHashable("quantity"): "79"]]
```

i.e the `id`, `quantity`, and `rate` of 3 products. But I don't want this in this format instead I want the first set of `id`, `rate` & `quantity` in one group, the second set of `id`, `rate` & `quantity` in another group & so on..

In short I want them in this format...

```
[{"remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id”:”4”}, {"remaining_balance”:”1.0”,”shipping_charges”:200, "grand_total”:456,”product_id”:”5”}]
```

Comment: You want JSON. Use `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Your Data is already in that format `[[:], [AnyHashable("id"): "5", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "499", AnyHashable("quantity"): "-1"], [AnyHashable("id"): "8", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "500", AnyHashable("quantity"): "79"], [AnyHashable("id"): "8", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "500", AnyHashable("quantity"): "79"]]`

Comment: ok..@Larme..can you maybe give some idea as to how..?

Comment: Observe `[AnyHashable("id"): "5", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "499", AnyHashable("quantity"): "-1"]`  Pair is Dictionary  Like `{"remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id”:”4”}`

Comment: @Larme May be  There is no relation between  `JSONSerialization` and question, He don't want to string representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry this is is also an Array of dictionary but you are confused between the JSON print format and Array of dictionary print format:

```
[[:], [AnyHashable("id"): "5", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "499", AnyHashable("quantity"): "-1"], [AnyHashable("id"): "8", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "500", AnyHashable("quantity"): "79"], [AnyHashable("id"): "8", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "500", AnyHashable("quantity"): "79"]]
```

Here this is a dictionary from your array:

```
[AnyHashable("id"): "5", AnyHashable("sellingPrice"): "499", AnyHashable("quantity"): "-1"],
```

You can verify it by iterating it:

```
for dict in arrayOfDictionary {
    print(dict)
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var arrayOfDictionary = [[String:Any]]()
var dictionary = ["id": "", "quantity": "","sellingPrice":""] as [String : Any]
    dictionary["id"] = product?.id
    dictionary["quantity"] = product?.quantity
    dictionary["sellingPrice"] = product?.theRate
    arrayOfDictionary.append(dictionary)

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOfDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
print(data)
let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
print(json)
```

Comment: ok @Salman Ghumsani...so how can I get it in this format...`[{"remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id”:”4”}, {"remaining_balance”:”1.0”,”shipping_charges”:200, "grand_total”:456,”product_id”:”5”}]
`

Comment: I am updating answer

Comment: instead of everything clumped together in 1 array as it seems in my case..

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: just a concern...is there a way to prevent duplicates..?

Comment: Duplicate what?

Comment: please look at this output printed...`[
  {
    "id" : "5",
    "sellingPrice" : "499",
    "quantity" : "-1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "5",
    "sellingPrice" : "499",
    "quantity" : "-1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "8",
    "sellingPrice" : "500",
    "quantity" : "79"
  },
  {
    "id" : "8",
    "sellingPrice" : "500",
    "quantity" : "79"
  }
]`

Comment: here the 1st entry is a duplicate. There should have been only 3 entries in the array. Can we prevent such duplicate occurences..?

Comment: Yes, You can prevent the ID-based not an issue.

Comment: no...in this particular case I cannot filter based on ID since 2 prducts under a same group can have the same id. The approach would be if the element is already in the array of dict. then don't add it. Else, add. Can we achieve this...?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare your dictionary explicitly as `[String:Any]` to get rid of the `AnyHashable`s while printing.

Second of all, it seems like you are trying to get a JSON format (when printing a Dictionary in Swift, you will get square brackets instead of curly ones), to get the JSON from the array of dictionaries, use `JSONSerialization`.

```
var arrayOfDictionary = [[String:Any]]()
var dictionary = ["id": "", "quantity": "","sellingPrice":""] as [String : Any]
dictionary["id"] = product?.id
dictionary["quantity"] = product?.quantity
dictionary["sellingPrice"] = product?.theRate
arrayOfDictionary.append(dictionary)
print(arrayOfDictionary) //[["id": "5", "sellingPrice": "-1", "quantity": "499"]]

do {
    let jsonArrayOfDict = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOfDictionary)
    print(String(data: jsonArrayOfDict, encoding: .utf8)!) //"[{\"id\":\"5\",\"sellingPrice\":\"-1\",\"quantity\":\"499\"}]"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You shouldn't actually convert the JSON to String, I just did that to show you the String format, you can use the `jsonArrayOfDict` variable of type `Data` to save your JSON data or upload it to a server through an API.

Comment: Actually @Dávid Pásztor the reason I wanted to convert them in to string was I had to pass all these values as parameter in my API call...

Comment: @bws as already stated in my answer, you should be fine with a variable of type `Data` for API calls. However, if the code above doesn't work for your API, please include an actual example of what you need to use as input arguments for your API calls.